# Unable to display XML using PHP

Tags: php

I have been trying to echo XML onto a webpage but I can't seem to get anything to appear.

```
<item>
<songid>US2HK18715</songid>
<songtitle>Take Me To The River</songtitle>
<artist>Al Green</artist>
<genre>Soul</genre>
<link>https://www.amazon.com/Take-Me-To-The-River/dp/B0023RP62U</link>
<releaseyear>1974</releaseyear>
</item>
```

That's an example of one of my XML items, here's the code i've been trying to use:

```
<?php 

$songs = simplexml_load_file('playlist.xml');

foreach($songs->item as $song){
    $id = $song->songid;
    $title = $song->songtitle;
    $artist = $song->artist;
    $genre = $song->genre;
    $link = $song->link;
    $releaseYear = $song->releaseyear;
    echo "<p><span>$id</span><span>$title</span></p>\n"; 
    echo "hello"; 


}
?>
```

Even the echo hello won't appear for some reason

Comment: Is the php able to open the xml file? Check if it's error out. if ($songs === false) {   echo 'Failed loading XML: ';} else { echo 'Loaded XML';}

Comment: Is there any extra tags before first <item> tag ?

Comment: Yeah it can, I tried print_r($songs); and it printed the whole file to the webpage

Comment: There's <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<rss version="0.91">
<channel>
<title>Music Playlist Sharing</title>
<description>Share music playlists - import from other applications and export them</description>
<language>en-us</language>

Comment: Post a functional example of `playlist.xml`. I'd guess `item` occurs multiple times and isn't the real parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your xml file format as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
<rss version="0.91"> 
  <channel> 
    <title>Music Playlist Sharing</title> 
    <description>Share music playlists - import from other applications and export them</description> 
    <language>en-us</language>
    <item>
      <songid>US2HK18715</songid>
      <songtitle>Take Me To The River</songtitle>
      <artist>Al Green</artist>
      <genre>Soul</genre>
      <link>https://www.amazon.com/Take-Me-To-The-River/dp/B0023RP62U</link>
      <releaseyear>1974</releaseyear>
    </item>
    <item>
    </item>
  </channel> 
</rss>
```

The below code should work.

```
foreach($songs->channel->item as $song){
  $id = $song->songid;
  $title = $song->songtitle;
  $artist = $song->artist;
  $genre = $song->genre;
  $link = $song->link;
  $releaseYear = $song->releaseyear;
  echo "<p><span>$id</span><span>$title</span></p>\n"; 
  echo "hello"; 
}
```